# How To Start Multiple Session

Tags: php

Hye, I've been creating this Quiz System, and I found myself in an error...The error started when I tried to add a DDOS Protection...Both start.php and configs.php started a session..and if the include function called start.php first, then it will only run start.php session and ignored the configs.php and vice versa. My question is how do i start both session at the same time so my website can work properly? Take a look at my code.

This is configs.php 
P/S : I cut of some code to keep it short

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
function rewrite_urls($change){
  $match = [
    '/userdetails.php\?id=([0-9]+)/',
    '/userdetails.php/',

    '/plans.php/',

    '/statistics.php\?id=([0-9]+)&t=([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/',

    '/quizzes.php\?request=my/',

    '/quizzes.php\?id=([0-9]+)&t=([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)&request=results&r=([0-9]+)/',
    '/quizzes.php\?id=([0-9]+)&t=([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)&request=results/',
    '/quizzes.php\?id=([0-9]+)&t=([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/',
    '/quizzes.php\?c=([0-9]+)\&t=([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)\&page=([0-9]+)/',
    '/quizzes.php\?c=([0-9]+)\&t=([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/',
    '/quizzes.php\?page=([0-9]+)/',
    '/quizzes.php/',
```

This is my start.php 
P/S : I cut of some code to keep it short

```
<?php 
/**
 * AntiDDOS System
 * FILE: index.php
 * By Sanix Darker
 */
function safe_print($value){
    $value .= "";
    return strlen($value) > 1 && (strpos($value, "0") !== false) ? ltrim($value, "0") : (strlen($value) == 0 ? "0" : $value);
}
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}
if(isset($_SESSION['standby'])){

    // There is all your configuration
    $_SESSION['standby'] = $_SESSION['standby']+1;

    $ad_ddos_query = 5;// ​​number of requests per second to detect DDOS attacks
    $ad_check_file = 'check.txt';// file to write the current state during the monitoring
    $ad_all_file = 'all_ip.txt';// temporary file
    $ad_black_file = 'black_ip.txt';// will be entered into a zombie machine ip
    $ad_white_file = 'white_ip.txt';// ip logged visitors
    $ad_temp_file = 'ad_temp_file.txt';// ip logged visitors
    $ad_dir = 'anti_ddos/files';// directory with scripts
    $ad_num_query = 0;// ​​current number of requests per second from a file $check_file
    $ad_sec_query = 0;// ​​second from a file $check_file
    $ad_end_defense = 0;// ​​end while protecting the file $check_file
    $ad_sec = date("s");// current second
    $ad_date = date("is");// current time
    $ad_defense_time = 100;// ddos ​​attack detection time in seconds at which stops monitoring
```

I also have head.php which will be called in every page

This is the code for head.php

```
<?php

try{
        if (!file_exists('anti_ddos/start.php'))
            throw new Exception ('anti_ddos/start.php does not exist');
        else
            require_once('anti_ddos/start.php'); 
    } 
    //CATCH the exception if something goes wrong.
    catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo '<div style="padding:10px;color:white;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;background:black;text-align:center;">'.
            'The <a href="https://github.com/sanix-darker/antiddos-system" target="_blank">"AntiDDOS System"</a> failed to load '.
            'properly on this Web Site, please de-comment the \'catch Exception\' to see what happening!</div>';
        //Print out the exception message.
        //echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
include __DIR__."/configs.php";

    
?>
```

Any Idea?

Comment: It's not PHP's job to prevent DDOS, frankly if an attack gets as far as the PHP script then you're already in way too much trouble, the server probably won't even be able to run the PHP scripts to check the IP etc. This sort of thing is the job of a perimeter firewall and associated tools.

Comment: Either have one file that is the only entry for your entire website that performs logic to load other files, or have a common set of includes that all files use in the same order. Also, you can’t have multiple sessions for a single request in PHP, so I’m not clear on what you mean there.